# IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL Bluescreen error in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bsod

my computer randomly gets `IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL` Bluescreen error.

SPECS:

[image: First screenshot of my specs]

[image: Second screenshot of my specs]

[image: Third screenshot of my specs]

Nothing specific triggers it - last time my computer lasted for 2 hours

I tried to uninstall all drivers with yellow mark in `Device manager` but somehow they are all back after the last reboot caused by this bluescreen.

This is a PC I just built so I didn't change any components.

The Windows installation itself crashed many times when I was installing it from USB.

Here are two DMP files from the Minidump folder: https://www.transfernow.net/dl/20230218XPI9GfWN

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142979/discussion-on-question-by-krystof-irql-not-less-or-equal-bluescreen-error-in-win); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the problem was but my PC worked when only one RAM stick was inserted. I decided to return both sticks and the guy in the shop said that he had the same problem - some BIOSes aren't ready for DDR5 yet and that I should wait for a BIOS update or return these sticks. I decided to buy one 16GB instead of 2x 8GB, and everything works great.
Check the chat section under this post.